# Tomcat jar loading

Tags: jar, tomcat6

I have created a web app in GWT and deployed it in Tomcat. I need to separate out some jars(Third party jars) from WEB-INF/lib and place them in a folder outside Tomcat setup. Please help me as of how to make appropriate changes so that on starting tomcat server those third party jars are loaded.

Comment: JARs outside WEB-INF/lib are not loaded by the container any more.

Answer (score 2):

In Tomcat6, you can place shared jars in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib` and it will be visible to all the web apps.

As the [docs clearly state](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html),

> Therefore, from the perspective of a
>   web application, class or resource
>   loading looks in the following
>   repositories, in this order:
>
> Bootstrap classes of your JVM
>
> System class loader classes (described
>   above)
>
> /WEB-INF/classes of your web
>   application
>
> /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web
>   application
>
> $CATALINA_HOME/lib
>
> $CATALINA_HOME/lib/*.jar

So if you have the same jar within your web-inf/lib, it will get loaded from there first. Ensure you remove duplicates.

Comment: if I need to load that jar from the root directory . I mean "/". Then what to do?